# xpatharrayiterator & xslt for-each

Tags: c#, xslt

I replaced an `xsl:for-each` statement by recursion like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="recursion">
<xsl:param name="current"/>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$current/*"/>

<xsl:variable name="test" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>

<xsl:if test="$test">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$test" mode="recursion">
    <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="somenode">

  <xsl:variable name="list">
    <xsl:copy-of select="extfunc:CSharpFunction()"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($list)/t[1]" mode="recursion">
    <xsl:with-param name="current" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>
```

The implementation of the CSharFunction looks like this:

```
public XPathNodeIterator CSharFunction()
{
    XmlNode rootXmlNode;

    //create xml tree
    //<ts>
    //  <t>...</t>
    //  ...
    //  <t>...</t>
    //</ts>

    return rootXmlNode.CreateNavigator().SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
}
```

When XslTransform reaches the line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$test" mode="recursion"> in
```

it throws an exception: `"Expression must evaluate to a node-set"`. As I noticed it happens only with xml trees returned from C# code and if I pass the `$text` variable to C# code it has the type of XPathArrayIterator.

How can I get rid of this annoying problem with the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply replace

```
  <xsl:variable name="list">
    <xsl:copy-of select="extfunc:CSharpFunction()"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

with

```
  <xsl:variable name="list" select="extfunc:CSharpFunction()"/>
```

and then you don't need the `msxsl:node-set` function.

And you can then simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]" mode="recursion">` to process the first `t` element in the list.

I have tried to reproduce the error you say you get but I can't; the XSLT sample I have tried in a .NET 4.5 console application is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl mf exsl"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="mf:GetNodeSet()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the C# is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace ConsoleApplication60
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
            proc.Load("../../XSLTFile1.xslt");

            XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
            xsltArgs.AddExtensionObject("http://example.com/mf", new Test1());

            proc.Transform("../../XMLFile1.xml", xsltArgs, Console.Out);
        }
    }

    public class Test1
    {
        public XPathNodeIterator GetNodeSet()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
            foreach (string s in new string[] { "foo", "bar", "kibo" })
            {
                XmlElement t = doc.CreateElement("t");
                t.InnerText = s;
                root.AppendChild(t);
            }
            return root.CreateNavigator().SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
        }
    }
}
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<t>foo</t>
<t>bar</t>
<t>kibo</t>
```

so I don't get an error and the elements created are processed just fine.

Comment: Without msxsl:node-set it throws the exception "_To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function.
_".

Comment: Have you made the replacement I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did as you said

Comment: public XPathNodeIterator CSharpFunction()
            {
                    rootXmlNode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ts", "");

                    foreach (string str in this.strings)
                    {
                        XmlNode textNode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "t", "");
                        textNode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateTextNode(str));
                        rootXmlNode.AppendChild(textNode);
                    }
return rootXmlNode.CreateNavigator().SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
            }

Comment: Are you really using `XslTransform`? Why not `XslCompiledTransform`?

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes 1. using XslCompiledTransform 2. I merely removed msxsl:node-set and it throws the exception "...node-set" 3. when I made suggested replacement and removed msxsl:node-set the xml tree not precessed at all i.e. tempaltes not applied

Comment: Fine, then I think using `XslCompiledTransform` and my suggestion you have a node set with `t` elements and thus instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($list)/t[1]" mode="recursion">` you simply need `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]" mode="recursion">` to apply templates to the first `t` element in the node set.

Comment: About XmlDocument and XmlElement, you want to say that I need to append rootXmlNode to XmlDocument to use it???

Comment: No, I simply wanted to see which nodes you construct to understand which nodes your C# function returns.

Comment: my 4th comment with function implementation. I made replacement, but it anyway throws the exception "... must evaluate to a node-set"

Comment: If you use `<xsl:variable name="list" select="extfunc:CSharpFunction()"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]" mode="recursion">` then I don't see why you would get an exception. And in one comment you said you don't get the exception, only the template is not applied. But `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]" mode="recursion">` should fix that problem.

Comment: I made changes that is `<xsl:variable name="list" select="extfunc:CSharpFunction()"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list[1]" mode="recursion">` exception thrown anyway. Templaltes not applied if I use $list\t[1] in `<xsl:apply-templates select="$list\t[1]" mode="recursion">`

Comment: When I pass `$list[1]` to C# code it has the type of `ResetableIterator`, but `<xsl:variable name="test" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>` has the type of `XPathArrayIterator` does it matter???

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what goes wrong, I have edited my answer with a complete sample that works for me. Please recheck your code whether it follows all suggestions made. If you still have problems then edit your question with a complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I've run your code and it works! I need some time to think.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I figured it out what was the problem, it's realy silly. In my original xslt file I forgot `select` attribute in `<with-param name="current"/>` beacuse of that the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="$current/*"/>` threw the exception. )))

Comment: Again forgot, thx, you simplified my code now it's more human-readable!